# Type.GetType method returns null value

Tags: c#, reflection

I have an enum in this namespace:

```
Andish.CSS.CommonSilverLight.Enum.Billing.AccountTransacts.AccountTransactAccountType
```

...and am using this method for convert the dataset to a class:

```
public List<T> ConvertTo<T>(DataTable datatable) where T : new()
    {
        var temp = new List<T>();
        try
        {
            var columnsNames = (from DataColumn dataColumn in datatable.Columns select dataColumn.ColumnName).ToList();
            temp = datatable.AsEnumerable().ToList().ConvertAll<T>(row => GetObject<T>(row, columnsNames));
            return temp;
        }
        catch
        {
            return temp;
        }

    }

 private T GetObject<T>(DataRow row, List<string> columnsName) where T : new()
    {
        T obj = new T();
        try
        {
            string columnname = "";
            string value = "";
            PropertyInfo[] Properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo objProperty in Properties)
            {
                columnname = columnsName.Find(name => name.ToLower() == objProperty.Name.ToLower());
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(columnname))
                {
                    value = row[columnname].ToString();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                    {
                        if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objProperty.PropertyType) != null)
                        {
                            value = row[columnname].ToString().Replace("$", "").Replace(",", "");
                            objProperty.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(value,
                                Type.GetType(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objProperty.PropertyType).ToString())), null);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            value = row[columnname].ToString().Replace("%", "");
                            objProperty.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(value,
                                Type.GetType(objProperty.PropertyType.ToString())), null);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return obj;
        }
        catch
        {
            return obj;
        }
    }
```

However, when I am debugging my code and have one int column in the dataset that converts to an enum property, this line:

```
objProperty.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(value,
    Type.GetType(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objProperty.PropertyType).ToString())), null);
```

...returns an error:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: conversionType
```

....and found that:

```
Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objProperty.PropertyType).ToString()
==
"Andish.CSS.CommonSilverLight.Enum.Billing.AccountTransacts.AccountTransactAccountType"
Type.GetType(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objProperty.PropertyType).ToString())
==
null
```

Why is `Type.GetType` not getting the type of my enum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objProperty.PropertyType)` directly.

It's useless to first call `ToString()` on it, and then use `Type.GetType(...)` on the string output!

(You make the same mistake in the `else` block, of course; instead of `Type.GetType(objProperty.PropertyType.ToString())`, just use `objProperty.PropertyType`.)

Answer (score 2):

Disregarding your code, [the documentation for `Type.GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) states:

> ## Parameters
>
> *typeName*
>
> **The assembly-qualified name of the type to get**. See [AssemblyQualifiedName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx). If the type is in the currently executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name qualified by its namespace.
>
> ...
>
> ## Return Value
>
> ...
>
> The type with the specified name, **if found**; otherwise, null.

Emphasis mine.

Presumably the type is not in the currently executing assembly, so you'll need to use the assembly-qualified name of the type. Instead of calling `ToString()`, try using the `AssemblyQualifiedName` property.

Comment: i change my code like this
 var value = row[columnname];
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
  {
     if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objProperty.PropertyType) != null)
       {
          Type type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objProperty.PropertyType);
          objProperty.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(value, type), null);
       }
     else
       {
          Type type = objProperty.PropertyType;
           objProperty.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(value, type), null);
       }
  }
But now i have this erro 
Invalid cast from
 'System.Int32' 
  to
 'AccountTransactAccountType'.

Answer (score 1):

i fixed this problem with change my code to this :

```
private T GetObject<T>(DataRow row, List<string> columnsName) where T : new()
    {
        T obj = new T();
        try
        {
            string columnname = "";

            PropertyInfo[] Properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo objProperty in Properties)
            {
                columnname = columnsName.Find(name => name.ToLower() == objProperty.Name.ToLower());
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(columnname))
                {
                    var value = row[columnname];

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
                    {

                        Type type;

                        type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objProperty.PropertyType) ?? objProperty.PropertyType;

                        objProperty.SetValue(obj,
                                             type == value.GetType()
                                                 ? Convert.ChangeType(value, type)
                                                 : System.Enum.ToObject(type, value), null);
                    }
                }
            }
            return obj;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return obj;
        }
    }
```